# Android studio incorrect gradle

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1.4

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.prototypr.io/how-to-create-an-android-icon-pack-app-ecb77811b938), and when I go to build APK I get the following:

```
Unsupported version of gradle
Update gradle and re-import project
Gradle settings
```

But when I go and `Update gradle and re-import project`, I get

```
Unsupported version of gradle:
Supported version is 2.2
Update gradle and re-import project
Gradle settings
```

And I get an infinite loop in this, rendering the development useless (since I can`t even devploy my application as an APK)

My Android Studio Version: 3.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and try to replace existing `ditributionUrl` with a newer version, say 4.5:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

Then re-import the project.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to build the APK right now, will edit this with my results. And thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Also Android Gradle plugin used in this project can be incompatible with newer Gradle version. If so, you would need to bump it as well. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin